# Java code cannot access Kotlin's package since Kotlin 1.0.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin along with Java in my gradle project. But since I've updated Kotlin (and kotlin-gradle-pludin) to 1.0.0 strange things began to happen. There's a Java class that uses Kotlin objects:

```
import com.myapp.android.entities.CategoryEntity;
import com.myapp.android.entities.CommentEntity;


public class Contract {

    private static final Class[] MODEL_CLASSES = new Class[]{
        CommentEntity.class,
        CategoryEntity.class
    };

}
```

CategoryEntity and CommentEntity are written in Kotlin. This code was compiling and working well until 1.0.0 but now I got the following errors:

> Error:(3, 1) error: package com.myapp.android.entities does not exist
>
> Error:(19, 13) error: cannot find symbol class CommentEntity
>
> Error:(20, 13) error: cannot find symbol class CategoryEntity

The code wasn't modified after update and what's interesting - Android Studio static analyzer threats this code as working, but not compiler.

I'm wonder - if I missed anything in the Release notes of Kotlin 1.0.0 or it's a bug in the compiler?

P.S. I've tried to put entities to the same package as the Contract class but "cannot find symbol class" errors didn't gone.

Here's a portion of the build.gradle of my app module

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        <...>
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        <...>
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

<...>

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    <...>
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    <...>
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    <...>

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 4
        versionName "0.0.4"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        <...>
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
```

SOLUTION:

As [Doug Stevenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson) pointed - there should be

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

in the build.gradle. Looks like I've accidentally replaced it with

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

instead of adding the new one. Now, when I returned kotlin-android plugin line everything works well.

Comment: Normally you `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` after 'com.android.application'.

Comment: You were right, man! Thanks!